# network device name is changed by itself

Tags: ubuntu, networking, usb, arm

I use a Ubuntu-arm, `uname -a`

```
Linux arm 3.7.8-x8 #1 SMP Sat Feb 16 04:15:13 UTC 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have two USB WiFi interfaces that are named wlan0 and wlan1 on `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

I run a script on each start-up that does:

```
ifdown wlan0 
rm /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0
ifup wlan0
wpa_supplicant -B -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/w.conf

ifdown wlan1
rm /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan1
ifup wlan1
wpa_supplicant -B -Dnl80211 -iwlan1 -c/etc/w2.conf
```

sometimes one of the interface is named as `rename5` whereas the other interface is named according to the `70-persistent-net.rules`.

Could anyone explain why it is named rename5 instead of wlan0 or wlan1 and how can I prevent that thing to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though not completely certain, I believe the root of your problem (which I too had to face, albeit on a different architecture) is [this kind of bugs](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56929) to which udev is prone. The important part of that post is where udev's developers state:

> We do no longer support renaming network interfaces in the kernel
>   namespace. Interface names are required to use custom names that
>   can never clash with the kernel created ones.
>
> We do not support swapping names; we cannot win any race against
>   the kernel creating new interfaces at the same time.
>
> We do no longer support the creation of udev rules from inside the
>   hotplug path.

And later in the same post:

> Predictable network interface names require a tool like biosdevname,
>   or **manually configured names, which do not use the kernel names**.

Both the bit about *names not clashing with kernel names* and that *not supporting swapping names* I believe apply to you.

While I cannot diagnose your system from afar, I think a good initial try might be choosing very different names, like nic1 and wifi-nic2.