# ping over wlanX when X is unknown

Tags: bash, ping

I've been running a bash script which updates the hosts table and tests a connection to a specific host. It runs successfully on a number of machines. Along the way, it checks communication with a given host using

```
ping -I wlan0 <host>
```

and

```
ping -I eth0 <host>
```

This worked fine until I tried using it on a machine whose (one and only) wireless device is a victim of udev shenanigans ([similar to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98452/network-device-name-is-changed-by-itself)), sometimes using wlan0 and other times wlan1.

Is there a reliable way of writing my bash script to ping with an arbitrary wlanX device, short of writing code for identifying which one the machine prefers to use on a given day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the interface used with this command (run as root) :

```
iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep -o "^\w*"
```

and the output will be, for example :

```
wlan0
```

You have to save the answer in a variable in your script

Comment: This identifies a suitable interface. My question was about whether an elegant solution exists **without** adding this line. I do acknowledge that I am being very picky here.

Comment: I wound up using something more or less like this answer. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Either of these two commands will list your non-loopback system interfaces, so you can iterate across them:

```
ip link | awk '$1+0>1 {print substr($2,1,length($2)-1)}'
netstat -i | awk 'NR>2 && $1 != "lo" {print $1}'
```

Alternatively you can tweak the `awk` condition to print only those lines starting with `wlan`:

```
ip link | awk '$1+0 && $2 ~ /^wlan/ {print substr($2,1,length($2)-1)}'
netstat -i | awk 'NR>2 && $1 ~ /^wlan/ {print $1}'
```

Comment: This identifies a suitable interface. My question was about whether an elegant solution exists **without** adding this line. I do acknowledge that I am being very picky here.

Comment: @JR. you've got me thinking more, here. I must say that I don't see how one can `ping` an arbitrarily named interface without identifying it first. There isn't really any concept of "_ping through a wireless interface_" (note the indefinite article) because that's meaningless when there are two or more wireless interfaces. There is the concept of "_ping through the particular wireless interface_", which is where you are at, but without identifying that interface one cannot choose it.